# How to set 3:4 Aspect Ratio Flutter camera preview

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, camera

I am working on Flutter app. I need camera functionality and decided to use [Camera Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) for this. I set the Aspect Ratio 3:4 but the image is warped and smaller than it should be. I think there is problem with scale. What is the correct way to set camera Aspect Ratio (i.e 3:4).

```
final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
final deviceRatio = size.width / size.height;
final aspectRatio=3/4;

Transform.scale(
        scale: controller.value.aspectRatio / deviceRatio,
        child: Center(
          child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: aspectRatio,
              child: CameraPreview(controller),
          )
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved my problem like this

```
final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

Transform.scale(
                scale: 1.0,
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 3.0 / 4.0,
                  child: OverflowBox(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      child: Container(
                        width: size,
                        height: size / controller.value.aspectRatio,
                        child: Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            CameraPreview(controller),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

Comment: Very nice solution. In my case, i use landscape mode, then i change the aspect ratio to 4/3 instead 3/4. Its works fine. Tks bro.

Answer (score 1):

```
RotatedBox(
              quarterTurns:
                  MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape
                      ? 3
                      : 0,
              child: Transform.scale(
                scale: 1.0,
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 3.0 / 4.0,
                  child: OverflowBox(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      child: Container(
                        width: size,
                        height: size / cameraController.value.aspectRatio,
                        child: Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            CameraPreview(cameraController),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
```